# Extracting the S from formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I am working on this formula. I have calculated all the values in it except for **S** . I want to extract **S** from formula (like S = .... ) , So I can put all the values in it and get the value of **S** .$$C = B\,\,{\log _2}\left( {1 + {S \over N}} \right)$$ I tried but this this **log** thing is confusing me out. I know that $${\log _a}y = x\,\, \Leftrightarrow \,\,{a^x} = y$$ But still I am not able to extract S. Please anybody help me as I have spent hours trying to solve this extraction step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have
$$\frac{C}{B}=log_2\left(1+\frac{S}{n}\right)$$
$$\left(2^{C/B}-1\right)N=S$$

Comment: Oh thanks, That hepled

Comment: that is nice and have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

$$C = B\,\,{\log _2}\left( {1 + {S \over N}} \right)\iff2^{\frac CB}=1+\frac SN.$$Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks, I get it